# How to remove all tags from a Wordpress post except a child tag using DOM

Tags: php, wordpress, dom, video

I'm trying to remove everything from the following string EXCEPT the object tag:

```
<p>If a post is marked video, and there is text BEFORE the video, the video player does not appear! We only see the actual text for the url…</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><object width="584" height="463"><param value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Clp9AeBdgL0?version=3" name="movie"><param value="true" name="allowFullScreen"><param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess"><embed width="584" height="463" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Clp9AeBdgL0?version=3"></object></p>
<p>Of course, you might even have a paragraph AFTER the video. Could be lots and lots of meaningless text &ndash; we should definitely limit this. Lorem ipsum</p>
```

As you can see above, the third 'p' tag contains an 'object' tag. I want to get rid of everything except the 'object' tag and its contents. In other words, I'd like to traverse the DOM and remove everything except:

```
<object width="584" height="463"><param value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Clp9AeBdgL0?version=3" name="movie"><param value="true" name="allowFullScreen"><param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess"><embed width="584" height="463" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Clp9AeBdgL0?version=3"></object>
```

I was able to write a function that removed any particular tag (p, img, div, etc) and its contents from a string, by traversing the DOM, but I could NOT figure out how to preserve the contents of a child tag like in this case. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of traversing the DOM with XML-parsed object (which is what it sounds like you're doing, sorry if I'm incorrect), I'd suggest just using a regular-expressions type search on your string.

[PHP supports PCREs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)

EDIT:
It looks like `'/<object .*<\/object>/'` works.  You can test PHP regex [here](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/) -- I used the `preg_match()` function.  Also, if you have multiple `<object>`s per page, you will want to make sure you're not using "greedy" matching.  Lastly, this **will not** work with nested objects, although I don't expect you'll have them.

So the whole snippet might be:

```
$pattern = '/<object .*<\/object>/';
$subject = /* this is your string containing the html' */
$matches = array();

if(preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches))
{
    echo $matches[0];
}
else
{
    echo "No match found."
}
```